# Perl dbi : fetchrow_array limit result :

Tags: perl, dbi

When I use the same request in mySQL Workbench, the count of results is 41100. 
In my script, the count is 1015. I have no error in my code (I use die for see it).
What is the cause of this difference?

```
# Create the statement 
# select all id in table contacts
$statement = "select distinct contacts.id from $database.contacts"; 

# Prepare and execute the SQL query 
$sqlQuery = $connectGrc->prepare($statement)

# Execute the statement 
$sqlQuery->execute() 

# Make id in array
while($oneId = $sqlQuery->fetchrow_array())
{
    push(@ArrayId,$oneId); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing obviously wrong (except for the lack of error checking and that your comments are not program comments). Try connecting with RaiseError on, 'use strict;', and see if there are problems which you otherwise might not see. Also, if all you want is a one-column array of results, and can settle for an array reference, consider selectcol_arrayref() for convenience.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong? It doesn't even compile! Who knows what his actual code looks like.